# React, как очистить данный state?

Tags: reactjs

есть такой state

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "", price: "", rating: "", weight: ""
  })
```

На input есть такое события

```
const onChangeHandler = event => {
    setForm({...form, [event.target.name] : event.target.value})
  }
```

Вопрос, после удачной отправки формы, как сделать что бы state для полей был ""
Если проще, как сделать что бы после отправки очищались поля

Comment: `setForm({});` можете просто пустой объект положить

Comment: @azlov К сожалению не очищает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае можно создать переменную в которой будет храниться начальное состояние. Имея данную переменную мы можем инициализировать начальное состояние и когда необходимо устанавливать состояние в исходное.

```
const initialState = { name: "", price: "", rating: "", weight: "" };
const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState);

...

const submitFormHandler = () => {
    // save form
    setForm(initialState );
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]